# change objects inside a set

Tags: ios, objective-c

I dont really know why this is so hard to find.. but basically I have a set in an object and I need to change the set's values.

The object may or may not be pre-populated with data but the user can make selections to populate this set.  Regardless of wether or not the set had data in it already, if the user does this I need to clear all the objects inside the set and replace it with what the user has chosen.

However, the setByAddingOjbectsFromArray method of NSSet does not recreate a new set if there is data already there.

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to keep what was in the set, what don't you use :

```
mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:myUserChoices];
```

Comment: if you do this, does the old set in memory get deallocated correctly in ARC?

Comment: Since it's not a problem without ARC (you're not changing the reference counter since this is an autorelease (no allocation call)), I think it should be OK with it

Answer (score 0):

Does NSMutableSet do what you need?

Comment: Yes, i can use NSMutableSet to add values to that set all day long.  the problem is I need to get that NSMutableSet into the object's NSSet.